# Bootstrap's popover does not show at the 1st hover (ajax)

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

HTML like this:

```
<a href="#"  data-studentId="01" data-toggle="popover">Student1</a>
<a href="#"  data-studentId="02" data-toggle="popover">Student2</a>
<a href="#"  data-studentId="03" data-toggle="popover">Student3</a>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $("a").hover(function(){
        var e = $(this);
        var studentId = e.attr('data-studentId');
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.***',
           type: 'get',
           data:{"studentId":studentId},
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(msg){//msg:  {name: "Lisa",gender: "female"}
              var content = '<div>' + msg.name + '</div>' + '<div>' + msg.gender + '</div>';
              e.popover({
                  html: true,
                  trigger: 'hover',
                  placement: 'bottom',
                  container: 'body',
                  content: content,
                  delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 200 }
              })
           }
       })
    })
})
```

When I hover $("a") at the 1st time, popover does not show.From the 2nd time, popover shows up. I searched SO for serval hours but didn't find a proper solution. I want popover shows up from the 1st time. Pls help me out. Many thanks!